# How to kill the youngest task in Hadoop Fair Scheduler

Tags: hadoop, scheduled-tasks, hadoop-yarn

I have very interesting use-case.
I’m running Apache Hadoop distribution latest version, with yarn.
The use-case is long computational jobs, that most work is compute intensive inside mapper part. I’m using fair scheduler for fair multi-user resource usage. Since task is long computation, I’m looking for a way to hint scheduler to kill the youngest task. Is that possible to configure Fair Scheduler to kill the youngest tasks?
If no such configuration, is that possible to inherit from fair scheduler and add such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can totally modify the [class](https://github.com/hopshadoop/hops/blob/master/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/fair/FairScheduler.java) to build your own.

Once you've built it and added it to the classpath you'd need to alter the configuration to use it similar to switching to [capacity scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Setting_up_ResourceManager_to_use_CapacityScheduler):

> Configuration
> Setting up ResourceManager to use CapacityScheduler
> To configure the ResourceManager to use the CapacityScheduler, set the following property in the conf/yarn-site.xml:
>
> ```
> Property  Value
> yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler
> ```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, in specific, I'm interested do I have a task start time information, and where is the decision which task to kill? I guess I need to change it somehow. Is it in FairScheduler class?